# PHP rename() from /tmp throws warning, although actually works

Tags: php, rename, permission-denied, tmp

Moving files from `/tmp` dir, I'm getting a warning:

> rename(/tmp/[somefile], [destination] ): Operation not permitted in [...]

There are three strange things with it:

1. Both the files in `/tmp` and the `[destination]` directory belong to `www` process (from behalf of whom the operation is executed) and have owner's permission for writing.
2. **The files actually end up being moved!**
3. Moving files across other directories, performed in the same way, works fine.

In other words, it actually works but throws a warning like it does not. Pretty weird to me.

What may be the reason of such behaviour?

Comment: Can be a issue with permissions, have you checked them?

Comment: @Jer, yes, read carefully: "Both the files in /tmp and the [destination] directory belong to www process (from behalf of whom the operation is executed) and have owner's permission for writing."

Answer (score 3):

Rename is supposed to be an atomic operation; I.e., there's never a time when both old and new file names exist or that neither exists. /tmp is usually a separate file system on Linux servers. My guess is that you're getting a warning because the move isn't atomic (because it's between two different file systems) even though it works. So this is probably closer to a copy followed by a delete instead of a move on one file system.

Example of a similar issue: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1272466

Comment: Looks like that, although not a single word about it in the docs. 
Your link was helpful, thanks. I considered using copy+unlink instead and it solved the problem.